# git missing date in commits

Tags: git, git-lfs

I converted some files to LFS using the following command:

```
git lfs migrate import --no-rewrite luca/models/weights/yolov5m.pt
```

However, when I do this, the commit that is generated is not valid. When I run `git fsck` I get, the following:

```
error in commit 1e394560481bc9b76efb42112a33470450006781: missingSpaceBeforeDate: invalid author/committer line - missing space before date
```

```
git show 1e394560481bc9b76efb42112a33470450006781
```

```
Author: John Doe <john@DOE.COM>
Date:   Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 +0000

    luca/models/weights/yolov5m.pt: convert to Git LFS
```

The date seems to be bogus.

Comment: What version of Git LFS are you using?